# javascript можно ли разделить значение в словаре и добавить их к новому ключу

Tags: javascript

Есть объект

```
var a = {

"фамилия имя отчество": "Дьяков Владимир Владимирович",
"год выпуска": "2017",
"пол": "Мужской",
"дата рождения": "24.09.1996"
}
```

можно ли получить вот такое значение в javascript:

```
b = {

"surname": "Дьяков",
"name": "Владимир",
"patronymic": "Владимирович",
"year_end": "2017",
"gender": "Мужской",
"birth_date": "24.09.1996"
}
```

Comment: Object.keys вернет массив ключей как строк. Дальше делаете с ними все что придумаете.

Comment: @Vitalii про Object.keys понятно, неочень могу понять как разделить значение ключа "фамилия имя отчество" и добавить эти значения соответствующим ключам

Comment: @ОлегИванов, если формат гарнтируется и будет именно: `фамилия<пробел>имя<пробел>отчество` то можно использовать `split`

Comment: Если вы не уверены в порядке создания этого ключа вы не можете гарантировать его корректный разбор.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```js
var oldObj = {
  "фамилия имя отчество": "Дьяков Владимир Владимирович",
  "год выпуска": "2017",
  "пол": "Мужской",
  "дата рождения": "24.09.1996"
}

console.log(remakeName(oldObj));

function remakeName(oldObj) {
  var newObj = {}

  var author = oldObj["фамилия имя отчество"].split(' ');
  newObj['surname'] = author[0];
  newObj['name'] = author[1];
  newObj['patronymic'] = author[2];
  newObj['year_end'] = oldObj["год выпуска"];
  newObj['gender'] = oldObj["пол"];
  newObj['birth_date'] = oldObj["дата рождения"];

  return newObj;
}
```

Имя разбиваем на массив методом split(' ') через каждый пробел. Важно чтобы имя фамилия и отчество всегда были через пробел и именно в таком порядке!